# C# flattening/expanding a 3D matrix into a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, expand, flatten

I have to flatted a 3d array in order to be serialized.
Let's start with this:

```
int[,,] array3D = new int[,,] { 
            { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, {5,6 }, {7,8 } },
            { { 9, 10}, { 11, 12},{ 13,14} , {15,16 }},
            { { 17, 18}, { 19, 20},{ 21,22}, {23,24 } }
        };
```

which makes it like this (something like 1,2,3,4,...,24):

[image]

So now I have this s/r

```
public static T[] Flatten<T>(T[,,] arr)
{
    int rows0 = arr.GetLength(0);
    int rows1 = arr.GetLength(1);
    int rows2 = arr.GetLength(2);
    T[] arrFlattened = new T[rows0 * rows1* rows2];

    int i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k < rows2; k++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < rows0; i++)
            {
                var test = arr[i, j, k];
                int index = i + j * rows0 + k * rows1;
                arrFlattened[index] = test;
            }
        }
    }
    return arrFlattened;
}
```

which flattens the 3d matrix into a 1d array

[image]

I am not smart enough to understand if the procedure is correct but let's go further.
I then Expand with the following s/r

```
public static T[,,] Expand<T>(T[] arr, int rows0, int rows1)
{
    int length = arr.GetLength(0);
    int rows2 = length / rows0 / rows1;

    T[,,] arrExpanded = new T[rows0, rows1, rows2];
    for (int k = 0; k < rows2; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows0; i++)
            {
                T test = arr[i + j * rows0 + k * rows1];
                arrExpanded[i, j, k] = test;
            }
        }
    }
    return arrExpanded;
}
```

but the result is the following:

[image]

So nothing like 1,2,3,4,5....24
I know that the error might be a trivial one but try as I might I can't find it.
Thank in advance.

Patrick

---

Thanks for helping all 3 solution were amazing and working but I chose the one more easily to understand and debug for me

Comment: Your 1d array is not jagged. A jagged array is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to know what is the mistake in your code more than you want to know the quickest way to get to the answer. Your index calculation is wrong. You are calculating it like this:

```
int index = i + j * rows0 + k * rows1;
```

But you actually need to multiply the last term not just by rows1 but by rows0 too:

```
int index = i + j * rows0 + k * rows1 * rows0;
```

Also, it makes sense to swap the order of dimensions that are iterated in for loops to get results in order. The final code for that would be:

```
    public static T[] Flatten<T>(T[,,] arr)
    {
        int rows0 = arr.GetLength(0);
        int rows1 = arr.GetLength(1);
        int rows2 = arr.GetLength(2);
        T[] arrFlattened = new T[rows0 * rows1* rows2];

        int i, j, k;
        for (k = 0; k < rows0; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < rows2; i++)
                {
                    var test = arr[k, j, i];
                    int index = i + j * rows2 + k * rows1 * rows2;
                    arrFlattened[index] = test;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrFlattened;
    }

    public static T[,,] Expand<T>(T[] arr, int rows0, int rows1)
    {
        int length = arr.GetLength(0);
        int rows2 = length / rows0 / rows1;

        T[,,] arrExpanded = new T[rows0, rows1, rows2];
        int i, j, k;
        for (k = 0; k < rows0; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < rows2; i++)
                {
                    T test = arr[i + j * rows2 + k * rows1 * rows2];
                    arrExpanded[k, j, i] = test;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrExpanded;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a help of *Linq* `OfType<T>()`, it's easy to have `int[]` from any multidimensional array:

```
var result = source.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

**Demo:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[,,] array3D = new int[,,] {
  { {  1,  2}, {  3,  4}, {  5,  6}, { 7,  8 } },
  { {  9, 10}, { 11, 12}, { 13, 14}, {15, 16 } },
  { { 17, 18}, { 19, 20}, { 21, 22}, {23, 24 } },
};

var result = array3D.OfType<int>().ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
```

We can use *modulo arithmetics* to `Expand` array back:

```
private static T[,,] Expand<T>(T[] value, int length1, int length2, int length3) {
  T[,,] result = new T[length1, length2, length3];

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    int r = i / (length3 * length2);
    int c = i /  length3 % length2;
    int h = i %  length3;

    result[r, c, h] = value[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

E.g.

```
int[,,] back = Expand(result, 3, 4, 2);
```

Comment: You solution seems very promising. That said I have to flatten into a 1d array in order to serialize it. Your flatten is int[][][] and not int[]. Could you please change it and also add the Expand method? thanks

Comment: @Patrick: so you want neither *multidimension*, nor *jagged* array, but good old `int[]`? And then given `int[]` you want to `Expand` it back into 3d one? If it is, let me put a question: from where lengths are come when expanding? Suppose you have `int[16]`, shall it be expanded `int[4,2,2]` or `int[2,4,2]` or even into `int[16,1,1]`?

Comment: Yes apolologies for not having made it clear. Yes I want to flatten into 1d (e.g. 3x4x2 into 1D ) and then expand by giving the original size (e.g. 3x4x2) which is known. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To **flatten** a multidimensional array just use `Cast<T>().ToArray()`.

```
var d3 = new int[,,]
{
    { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, {5,6 }, {7,8 } },
    { { 9, 10}, { 11, 12},{ 13,14} , {15,16 }},
    { { 17, 18}, { 19, 20},{ 21,22}, {23,24 } }
};
var d1 = d3.Cast<int>().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", d1));
```

Gives:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

To **expand** use this:

```
static int[,,] Expand(int[] array, int size2, int size3)
{
    var size = new[] { array.Length / size2 / size3, size2, size3 };
    var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), size);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        res.SetValue(array[i], GetMultidimensionalIndex(i, size));

    return (int[,,])res;
}

static int[] GetMultidimensionalIndex(int index, int[] size)
{
    var factors = size.Select((item, i) => size.Skip(i).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b)).ToArray();
    var factorsHelper = factors.Zip(factors.Skip(1).Append(1), (Current, Next) => new { Current, Next }).ToArray();
    return factorsHelper.Select(item => index % item.Current / item.Next).ToArray();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var d3 = new int[,,]
{
    { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, {5,6 }, {7,8 } },
    { { 9, 10}, { 11, 12},{ 13,14} , {15,16 }},
    { { 17, 18}, { 19, 20},{ 21,22}, {23,24 } }
};
Console.WriteLine("Original:");
Print3DArray(d3);

var flat = d3.Cast<int>().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("Flat:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", flat));

var expanded = Expand(flat, d3.GetLength(1), d3.GetLength(2));
Console.WriteLine("Expanded:");
Print3DArray(expanded);
```

with helper method:

```
static void Print3DArray(int[,,] array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("    {");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {");
            for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                Console.Write($" {array[i, j, k]}");
            }
            Console.Write(" }");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" }");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("}");
}
```

Gives:

```
Original:
{
    { { 1 2 } { 3 4 } { 5 6 } { 7 8 } }
    { { 9 10 } { 11 12 } { 13 14 } { 15 16 } }
    { { 17 18 } { 19 20 } { 21 22 } { 23 24 } }
}
Flat:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
Expanded:
{
    { { 1 2 } { 3 4 } { 5 6 } { 7 8 } }
    { { 9 10 } { 11 12 } { 13 14 } { 15 16 } }
    { { 17 18 } { 19 20 } { 21 22 } { 23 24 } }
}
```

Comment: Wow great thanks!! And the expand method? Obviously you need to pass 2 integers in order to restore the original size for X,Y,Z (rows, columns, planes)

Comment: You solution gets better and better. But                              1st: I  don't need 3 sizes but 2 since I can get the 3rd from the lenght of the 1d dividing by the other 2 sizes.                  2nd would it be possible an expand method like that Expand(int[] flattend, int size2, int size3) ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Patrick, I checked the dividing stuff works really faster than `GetLength`. That's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a go:

```
void Main()
{
    int[,,] array3D = new int[,,]
    {
        { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, {5,6 }, {7,8 } },
        { { 9, 10}, { 11, 12},{ 13,14} , {15,16 }},
        { { 17, 18}, { 19, 20},{ 21,22}, {23,24 } }
    };

    var flattened = array3D.Cast<int>().ToArray();

    var restored = Expand(flattened, 3, 4);
}

public static T[,,] Expand<T>(T[] arr, int rows0, int rows1)
{
    int length = arr.GetLength(0);
    int rows2 = length / rows0 / rows1;
    int x = 0;

    T[,,] arrExpanded = new T[rows0, rows1, rows2];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows0; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows2; k++)
            {
                T test = arr[x++];
                arrExpanded[i, j, k] = test;
            }
        }
    }
    return arrExpanded;
}
```

It worked fine for me.