# Assign 1D array values to multidimensional array, of unknown dimensions / type

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have an N-dimensional array which I want to be able to assign any primitive value to. (one type for single array, but alg must be generic for all primitive types).

I've written a method which can do this:

```
var element = Array.CreateInstance(dataType, dataDims);

foreach (var index in GetIndexes(dataDims))
{
     element.SetValue(SomeKindOfValue, index);
}
```

The function GetIndexes generates all possible indexes for the given dimensions:

```
     public static IEnumerable<int[]> GetIndexes(int[] dims)
     {
        int lastIndex = dims.Length - 1;
        int lastDim = dims[lastIndex];
        int[] Index = new int[dims.Length];
        int currentDim = lastIndex;

        while (currentDim >= 0) 
        {
            if (currentDim == lastIndex)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lastDim; i++)
                {
                    yield return Index;
                    Index[currentDim]++;
                }

                Index[currentDim] = 0;
                currentDim--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Index[currentDim] == dims[currentDim] - 1)
                {
                    Index[currentDim] = 0;
                    currentDim--;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    Index[currentDim]++;
                    currentDim = lastIndex;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EXAMPLE: for GetIndexes(new int[] {4,2,3}) the output will be:

```
0, 0, 0 |
0, 0, 1 |
0, 0, 2 | 
0, 1, 0 | 
0, 1, 1 |
0, 1, 2 | 
1, 0, 0 | 
1, 0, 1 | 
1, 0, 2 | 
1, 1, 0 | 
1, 1, 1 | 
1, 1, 2 | 
2, 0, 0 | 
2, 0, 1 | 
2, 0, 2 | 
2, 1, 0 | 
2, 1, 1 | 
2, 1, 2 | 
3, 0, 0 | 
3, 0, 1 | 
3, 0, 2 | 
3, 1, 0 | 
3, 1, 1 | 
3, 1, 2 |
```

The problem is, that assigning values this way is time-costly, and this alg need to be as efficient as possible.

I was thinking that multidimensional array is actually 1d array in the memory, so if I could access the pointer of each element, then I could assign the values w/o any calculations, and directly. The problem is that I was unable to find a way to create a pointer to a generic class Array(or to it's first element).

Basically, I'm trying to write a generic func of this (which will accept any primitive type as datatype of array, and will accept any multidimensional array):

```
public static unsafe void SetElementsByPointer(int[,] array, int[] values)
{
            if (values.Length != array.LongLength)
                 throw new Exception("array and values length mismatch.");

            fixed (int* pStart = array)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.LongLength; i++)
                {
                    int* pElement = pStart + i;
                    *pElement = values[i];
                }
            }
        }
```

I will appreciate any other ideas for setting values into n-dimensional array, but the pointer way seems the most efficient, just that I can't figure it out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you even trying to archive here? Copy a plain `{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 }` array into a multidim `{ { 1 2 } { 3 4 } { 5 6 } }` array?

Comment: copy {1,2,3,4,5} into multidimentional array of sama data type meaning generic func for {1,2,3,4,5,6} -> {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}} or {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} -> {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}} and so on... 1d array to ND array where N is NOT known.

Comment: That did not really answered my question... What is `GetIndexes` doing exactly? it looks horribly complicated and probably is key to understanding what you are trying to archive here.

Comment: GetIndexes returns all possible indexes for the n-dimentional array. for example: if  array dimensions are [2,4,5] then it will return: {0,0,0} {0,0,1}{0,0,2}... {0,0,4} {0,1,0}, {0,1,1}.... till the last index: {1,3,4} it will return all possible indexes for this ND array in order from smallest to largest.

Comment: provide some example

Comment: for GetIndexes(new int[] {4,2,3}) the output will be: 0, 0, 0 |
0, 0, 1 |
0, 0, 2 | 
0, 1, 0 | 
0, 1, 1 |
0, 1, 2 | 
1, 0, 0 | 
1, 0, 1 | 
1, 0, 2 | 
1, 1, 0 | 
1, 1, 1 | 
1, 1, 2 | 
2, 0, 0 | 
2, 0, 1 | 
2, 0, 2 | 
2, 1, 0 | 
2, 1, 1 | 
2, 1, 2 | 
3, 0, 0 | 
3, 0, 1 | 
3, 0, 2 | 
3, 1, 0 | 
3, 1, 1 | 
3, 1, 2 |

Comment: so your `int[]` is literally just saying that in this case, you got the multi-dim array `T[4,2,3]` ? and the new value `SomeKindOfValue` is always the same? or does it differ in any way?

Comment: yea, my int[] is the dimensiosn of the T[,,]. and SomeKindOfValue is different for different indexes. in SetElementsByPointer func the values[] variable is the value for each index for example. (meaning total number of elements in values[] and array[,] is the same)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475059/10958092).

Comment: hey alex. the problem is that the multidimentional array may have any number of dimentions and any type of data (which is primitive). SetElementsByPointer only handles array of 2 dimensions with dataType int, but i need a func to handle ANY primitive data type and ANY number of dimensions.

Comment: The most simple way of doing this would be to just use a wrapper around the actual array. The more complicated requires unsafe code. And then there also still is the option of using T4 Templates

Comment: @X39, i was thinking that any multidimentional array is 1d array in memory, so if we can just access it's elements' pointers by order, and assign values to them with a simple loop, then it might work. the problem is that i can't figure a way to do it. maybe you can elaborate on the wrapper class? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy stuff, you may use this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTzJv4

```
// 1D array
int[] values = new int[] {
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6
};
// 2D array
int[,] marr = new int[2,3];

// Copy here
System.Buffer.BlockCopy((Array)values, 0, (Array)marr, 0, (int)marr.LongLength * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: WOW didn't i think that buffer copy is compatible for arrays of different dimensions. Thanks! :) guess i'll have to do a switch for each element type tho, because it might be a byte array as well as float / double and so on. (all primitive types)